# Java Regular Expression Won't Validate

Tags: java, regex

so i've been trying to do a simple java syntax checker. I'm using regular expressions to check each and every line written on the textarea (the code) to see if it's correctly written. The problem i'm having is the regular expression won't validate it correctly, it validates it as False (error on the code) when it's true (the code is written correctly). So I don't know if the prblem is my Regular Expression or am I doing it all wrong.

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Code i'm using:

```
    String codeText = codeTxt.getText().trim(); //Code from textarea
    String errors   = ""; //Saves the errors from the code
    int openBrace   = 0;  //Check if we open a curly brace.

    //Break lines by new line.
    String lines[] = codeText.split("\\r?\\n");

    //Regular Expresiona
    String libraries = "(import) (javax)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\.\\*;)",
           classCheck = "(public|private) class ([a-zA-Z]+) (extends ([a-zA-Z]+))?\\{";

    //If first line is an import
    if(lines[0].matches(libraries) == false){
        errors += "- Error on line: " + String.valueOf(1) + " - " + lines[0] + "\n";
    }

    //Check rest of lines
    for(int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++){

        if(lines[i].matches(classCheck) == false && lines[i].equals("") == false){
           errors += "- Error on line: " + String.valueOf(i + 1) + " - " + lines[i] + "\n";

        }else if(lines[i].matches(classCheck) == true && lines[i].equals("") == false){
            openBrace++; //Indicates how many curly braces are opened.

        }

    }

    //Print errors
    if(errors.equals("")){
        consoleTxt.setText("Correct syntax.");
    }else{
        consoleTxt.setText(errors);
    }
```

Comment: what is your input (example), and what does the program do then? Got a StrackTrace? Or which line raises the error?

Comment: @luksch *simple java syntax checker* probably a simple java program.

Comment: the checker is clearly only concerned with import and class definition lines so far. Still, I want to know what the OP is feeding it and what he really expects. There is a lot missing still, even only for the import and class lines. Also, usually the first line in a java program is a comment and then comes the package definition.

Comment: That's true luksch about the first line being the package name, i forgot about that. But the input is just some Java Code, i then put all the lines from the code into an array and begin checking line by line. The output is just a message "Syntax Correct" or all the errors it picked up along the way, for example if a curly brace wasn't closed or if a line of the code was spelled wrong..

Comment: @ExoSkeleton321 when you want to validate a programming language, don't use regex. it's not going to work quickly at all. Additionally, your regular expressions will quickly get out of hand and they likely won't catch all possible cases. This will be more helpful for you: http://parsingintro.sourceforge.net/ try using a lexer and parser for validation

Comment: @iismathwizard Thanks for the advice, i'll check it out.

Comment: Try regex101.com to debug this

Comment: I actually tested it out on regexr.com and it worked.

Comment: Where is your attempt? I suspect leading/trailing whitespace might be a problem, try: `String libraries = "\\s*(import) (javax)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\.\\*;)\\s*",
           classCheck = "\\s*(public|private) class ([a-zA-Z]+) (extends ([a-zA-Z]+))?\\{\\s*";`